# forで取得したフォルダごとにサブフォルダ以下全ファイルを検索するfor文の書き方を教えてください

Tags: batch-file

あるフォルダの「直下のフォルダリスト」と「直下フォルダ1つに含まれるサブフォルダ含むすべてのファイルリスト」を取得したいのですが、Batの構文がよくわからなくてエラーになります。

```
for /d %%A in ("Z:\親フォルダ\*") do (　←これは動く
    echo %%A
    for /r %%A %%B IN (*) DO (　←%Bの使い方が不正というエラーになる。%%Aの参照方法が不明
        echo %%B
    )
)
```

およそ間違った構文なのはわかるのですが、%%Aを二つ目のfor文（サブフォルダ探索用）に使う方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

内側の`for`の処理を、ラベルを使ったサブルーチン化して外に出し、`call`で呼ぶ方法があります。
以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
for /d %%A in ("Z:\親フォルダ\*") do (
    echo %%A
    call :subfor %%A
)
exit /b

:subfor
for /r %1 %%B IN (*) DO (
    echo %%B
)
```

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。ご回答ありがとうございます。実行できました。